# Can a generator in an electrical grid be destroyed by disconnecting the power at a distant substation

Tags: generator, transmission-line, power-grid

I've read that if the length of a transmission line is a quarter wavelength then an open circuit at the sink would appear as a short at the source.

Consider a real electrical power transmission line of quarter wavelength in size (Approximately 1000 km) between a generator and a substation. If the substation happens to disconnect and isolate itself from the transmission line for maintenance, wouldn't that appear as a short to the generator and damage it (Ignoring any protection equipment at the generator).

How is this scenario avoided in power grids? Do they layout the length such that it is not a quarter wavelength?

Comment: These generators have a phenomenal amount of protection built around them to prevent self destruction. That wire is part of a grid so it goes to more then point a & B.

Comment: Long lines, in this case, are considered as "inductive", but there can be transients which are well managed.

Comment: You're conflating 2 different ideas here. The term "Transmission Line" is used in both an RF context as well as a power distribution context, but they don't refer to the same thing.

Comment: @brhans, power transmission lines are "transmission lines" in the same sense as RF transmission lines. But, the wavelength is thousands of kilometers, and the actual lines usually are much shorter than one wavelength.

Answer (score 4):

> I've read that if the length of a transmission line is a quarter wavelength then an open circuit at the sink would appear as a short at the source.

Usually this is applied to lines carrying radio frequency signals.

> Consider a real electrical power transmission line of quarter wavelength in size (Approximately 1000 km) between a generator and a substation. If the substation happens to disconnect and isolate itself from the transmission line for maintenance, wouldn't that appear as a short to the generator and damage it (Ignoring any protection equipment at the generator).

Assuming that the generator was impedance matched to the transmission line then yes it could appear as a short.  but generators are inherently current limited. so that wouldn't damage the generator.

> How is this scenario avoided in power grids? Do they layout the length such that it is not a quarter wavelength?

At 1000km usually DC is used instead of AC.
also line reactors (series inductance) on AC links are going to mess with this too, making them seem longer than they are.